# Paperclip not saving files with save()

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I have a little problem with paperclip saving the data passed through the form...
If I'm trying to save the record with .save() it won't save.. When I look in the server/log there are no errors or warnings for the paperclip gem :-/

```
# trying to save the record with save() -- not working :-/
def create
  @baan_import = BaanImport.new(params[:baan_import])
  if @baan_import.save
    redirect_to(baan_imports_url)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Server-log: (using .save() in controller)
https://gist.github.com/1327347

I just don't get it why it's working if I'm using .create instead of .save()

```
# trying to save the record with Model.create() -- working!
def create
  @baan_import = BaanImport.create(params[:baan_import])
  redirect_to(baan_imports_url)
end
```

Server-log: (using .create() in controller)
https://gist.github.com/1327359

Can some one explain me why it's working with create and not with save??

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show us the `BaanImport` model.  My first guess is you're possibly missing `baan_upload` in `attr_accessible` on your model, and as a result, Rails will not let you mass assign the file parameter for upload.

Can you also confirm (would appear as though it's properly set up) that your form has `html => {:multipart => true}` as an option?

Comment: Well I used the attr_accessible :baan_upload before i posted my question... I don't know why -- but it's working now ><

I don't get it... shouldn't the application yield the warning
WARNING: Can't mass-assign these protected attributes: foo_bar
?

Comment: It usually does, but perhaps it's because the method's hidden away in paperclip (it's being stripped out before it gets to paperclip?), not sure.   Depending on your rails set up, you may have had to restart the server for the attr_accessible to take effect.